# Apache Pig Problem - Use order by then limit data is not working

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a problem.
When I load input data, Then I caculate the data, Order data by name, then I try to get the top 3 data but has some problems.
Here is the log file
dump data;

```
(Tainan,57)
(Taipei,121)
(Hsinchu,53)
(Hualien,44)
(Taitung,50)
(Taoyuan,72)
(Pingtung,59)
(Taichung,63)
(Kaohsiung,89)
```

then use order data by $1 desc:

```
(Taipei,121)
(Kaohsiung,89)
(Taoyuan,72)
(Taichung,63)
(Pingtung,59)
(Tainan,57)
(Hsinchu,53)
(Taitung,50)
(Hualien,44)
```

but when i try to use command : data = limit data 3;
and dump it. it has problem.

```
HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
3.2.2   0.17.0  hadoop  2021-05-05 19:49:54 2021-05-05 19:49:55 GROUP_BY,ORDER_BY,LIMIT

Some jobs have failed! Stop running all dependent jobs

Job Stats (time in seconds):
JobId   Maps    Reduces MaxMapTime  MinMapTime  AvgMapTime  MedianMapTime   MaxReduceTime   MinReduceTime   AvgReduceTimMedianReducetime    Alias   Feature Outputs
job_local586139516_0006 1   1   n/a n/a n/a n/a n/a n/a n/a n/a q11 SAMPLER 
job_local708055803_0005 1   1   n/a n/a n/a n/a n/a n/a n/a n/a a,c0,l,q10  GROUP_BY    

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_local1801700609_0007    q11 ORDER_BY,COMBINER   Message: Job failed!    

Input(s):
Successfully read 608 records from: "file:///home/hadoop/mid/profile.txt"

Output(s):

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_local708055803_0005 ->  job_local586139516_0006,
job_local586139516_0006 ->  job_local1801700609_0007,
job_local1801700609_0007    ->  null,
null


2021-05-05 19:49:55,716 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl - JobTracker metrics system already initialized!
2021-05-05 19:49:55,718 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl - JobTracker metrics system already initialized!
2021-05-05 19:49:55,720 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl - JobTracker metrics system already initialized!
2021-05-05 19:49:55,736 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl - JobTracker metrics system already initialized!
2021-05-05 19:49:55,745 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl - JobTracker metrics system already initialized!
2021-05-05 19:49:55,749 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl - JobTracker metrics system already initialized!
2021-05-05 19:49:55,755 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Some jobs have failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2021-05-05 19:49:55,758 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias q12
Details at logfile: /home/hadoop/mid/pig_1620215111006.log
```

Comment: Are you re-using the relation name `data`? If so, could you try giving each relation a unique name e.g. `limited = LIMIT data 3; DUMP limited;`

Comment: @pauljcg I try to use your suggestion, but not working

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved this problem. People who meet this problem only need to change the version of their java into java8. This error will happen when the version of your java is too high, such as java11.